# Opencart : Permission Denied Error

Tags: php, opencart, opencart2.x, opencart-module

I have made a custom module on Opencart. But while Editing It's showing Following Error:

[image]

For that I have followed the steps also. But still getting same Error:

```
   1. Login to admin, go to System > User Group.
   2.  Edit your admin usergroup (probably Top Administrator group).
   3. Add permission to your new extension modules (both Access Permission and Modify Permission).
```

Here's my controller Demo if any problem there :

```
<?php
class Controllerextensionmodulehelloworld extends Controller {
    private $error = array(); // This is used to set the errors, if any.

    public function index() {
        // Loading the language file of helloworld
        $this->load->language('extension/module/helloworld'); 

        // Set the title of the page to the heading title in the Language file i.e., Hello World
        $this->document->setTitle($this->language->get('heading_title'));

        // Load the Setting Model  (All of the OpenCart Module & General Settings are saved using this Model )
        $this->load->model('setting/setting');

        // Start If: Validates and check if data is coming by save (POST) method
        if (($this->request->server['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') && $this->validate()) {
            // Parse all the coming data to Setting Model to save it in database.
            $this->model_setting_setting->editSetting('helloworld', $this->request->post);

            // To display the success text on data save
            $this->session->data['success'] = $this->language->get('text_success');

            // Redirect to the Module Listing
            $this->response->redirect($this->url->link('extension/module', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'));
        }

        // Assign the language data for parsing it to view
        $data['heading_title'] = $this->language->get('heading_title');

        $data['text_edit']    = $this->language->get('text_edit');
        $data['text_enabled'] = $this->language->get('text_enabled');
        $data['text_disabled'] = $this->language->get('text_disabled');
        $data['text_content_top'] = $this->language->get('text_content_top');
        $data['text_content_bottom'] = $this->language->get('text_content_bottom');      
        $data['text_column_left'] = $this->language->get('text_column_left');
        $data['text_column_right'] = $this->language->get('text_column_right');

        $data['entry_code'] = $this->language->get('entry_code');
        $data['entry_layout'] = $this->language->get('entry_layout');
        $data['entry_position'] = $this->language->get('entry_position');
        $data['entry_status'] = $this->language->get('entry_status');
        $data['entry_sort_order'] = $this->language->get('entry_sort_order');

        $data['button_save'] = $this->language->get('button_save');
        $data['button_cancel'] = $this->language->get('button_cancel');
        $data['button_add_module'] = $this->language->get('button_add_module');
        $data['button_remove'] = $this->language->get('button_remove');

        // This Block returns the warning if any
        if (isset($this->error['warning'])) {
            $data['error_warning'] = $this->error['warning'];
        } else {
            $data['error_warning'] = '';
        }

        // This Block returns the error code if any
        if (isset($this->error['code'])) {
            $data['error_code'] = $this->error['code'];
        } else {
            $data['error_code'] = '';
        }     

        // Making of Breadcrumbs to be displayed on site
        $data['breadcrumbs'] = array();
        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text'      => $this->language->get('text_home'),
            'href'      => $this->url->link('common/home', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'),
            'separator' => false
        );
        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text'      => $this->language->get('text_module'),
            'href'      => $this->url->link('extension/module', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'),
            'separator' => ' :: '
        );
        $data['breadcrumbs'][] = array(
            'text'      => $this->language->get('heading_title'),
            'href'      => $this->url->link('extension/module/helloworld', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'),
            'separator' => ' :: '
        );

        $data['action'] = $this->url->link('extension/module/helloworld', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'); // URL to be directed when the save button is pressed

        $data['cancel'] = $this->url->link('extension/module', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'); // URL to be redirected when cancel button is pressed

        // This block checks, if the hello world text field is set it parses it to view otherwise get the default 
        // hello world text field from the database and parse it
        if (isset($this->request->post['helloworld_text_field'])) {
            $data['helloworld_text_field'] = $this->request->post['helloworld_text_field'];
        } else {
            $data['helloworld_text_field'] = $this->config->get('helloworld_text_field');
        }   

        // This block parses the status (enabled / disabled)
        if (isset($this->request->post['helloworld_status'])) {
            $data['helloworld_status'] = $this->request->post['helloworld_status'];
        } else {
            $data['helloworld_status'] = $this->config->get('helloworld_status');
        }

        $data['header'] = $this->load->controller('common/header');
        $data['column_left'] = $this->load->controller('common/column_left');
        $data['footer'] = $this->load->controller('common/footer');

        $this->response->setOutput($this->load->view('extension/module/helloworld.tpl', $data));

    }

    /* Function that validates the data when Save Button is pressed */
    protected function validate() {

        // Block to check the user permission to manipulate the module
        if (!$this->user->hasPermission('modify', 'extension/module/helloworld')) {
            $this->error['warning'] = $this->language->get('error_permission');
        }

        // Block to check if the helloworld_text_field is properly set to save into database,
        // otherwise the error is returned
        if (!$this->request->post['helloworld_text_field']) {
            $this->error['code'] = $this->language->get('error_code');
        }
        /* End Block*/

        // Block returns true if no error is found, else false if any error detected
        if (!$this->error) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Find

```
$this->response->redirect($this->url->link('extension/module', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'));
```

Replace

```
$this->response->redirect($this->url->link('extension/extension', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&type=module', true));
```

**For Cancel Button**

Find

```
   $data['cancel'] = $this->url->link('extension/module', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'); // URL to be redirected when cancel button is pressed
```

Replace with

```
$data['cancel'] = $this->url->link('extension/extension', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&type=module', true);
```

**For save button action**

Find

```
 $data['action'] = $this->url->link('extension/module/helloworld', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], 'SSL'); // URL to be directed when the save button is pressed
```

Replace

```
if (!isset($this->request->get['module_id'])) {
        $data['action'] = $this->url->link('extension/module/helloworld', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'], true);
    } else {
        $data['action'] = $this->url->link('extension/module/helloworld', 'token=' . $this->session->data['token'] . '&module_id=' . $this->request->get['module_id'], true);
    }
```

Comment: I have added the Controller file with the Question and yes it's there in validate function

Comment: exactly when are you getting message "Permission denied".

Comment: Yes, it worked!
But can you please explain how it works  or what was the wrong please?

Comment: you missed  "&type=module" as you extension type is module & missed "&module_id" on action button

Comment: I think this is going to work for me to.  Reminder to all - Modules are case sensitive - just spent an age looking for the wrong case letter.  Original is from here: https://code.tutsplus.com/articles/from-beginner-to-advanced-in-opencart-more-module-development--cms-22289

Comment: And in case you are looking for a 2.0 version - it is here: https://github.com/mariavilaro/OpenCart-2-Hello-World-Module

Comment: Partial success - anyone know a decent HelloWorld install for Opencart 2.3.0.2 - this has had me in circles for hours now ...

Answer (score 0):

Go to

```
system->users->users group->Administrator->edit
```

Here you can see Access Permission & Modify Permission, Please select all here & save that's it. Now you can access your custom moudle.